# Loop invariant when first iteration starts

Tags: algorithm, loops, insertion-sort, invariants, loop-invariant

I'm taking an elementary course in data structures & algorithms, the book we use is the seminal work by CLRS. I have some trouble understanding the loop invariant as explained in chapter 2.1: Insertion Sort.

The book says that:

> At the start of each iteration of the for loop of lines 1-8, the subarry A[1..j -1] consists of the elements originally in A[1..j-1], but in sorted order.

Now, this puzzles me. Why does this hold when the first iteration starts? 
Say the array to be sorted looks like { 5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3 }. Now when the first iteration of the for loop starts A[1.. j-1] isn't in sorted order, when the iteration ends it is though.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A[1.. j-1] isn't in sorted order, when the iteration ends it is
>   though.

Assuming the value of `j` starts at 2 initially, `A[1.. j-1]` will only contain an array of length 1, which by definition is sorted.